# create pie chart using javascript or jquery without any external API

Tags: javascript, charts

Any one know how to create PIE chart for data from db [table] using pure JS.

There are some tools like google chart, Rgraph and other. But I dont want any external calls. So anyone has any idea about creating independant pie chart?

Comment: most tools can be installed locally without any external call. Google Charts is the exception.